# Simple sound player function call

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, void

I would like to ask what should I write down to play function e1play when button "start" is pressed.  I want to play cat.wav sound. How to call it. When I make for example [MainView e1play] it shows me some errors. Please help.

Here is my h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h> 
@interface MainView : UIView {
AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer1;
}
- (void)e1play:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender;
```

And m file

```
@implementation MainView
- (void)e1play:(id)sender{ //function to play sound of the cat
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cat" ofType:@"wav"];
avPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[avPlayer1 play];
}
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender{  //button to lunch function e1play
//??????
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need something simple like playing sound, you probably should go this way:

- create system sound with
  `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID`
- play system sound with `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`
- dispose system sound with `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID`

... you only need to store SystemSoundID for each sound you would like to play.

Comment: but apple says that "No longer than 30 seconds in duration" for files played. so please if someone could help to repair code i wrote, please\